# Mapping array of objects in React - unexpected token

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have an array of objects like so:

```
{
_id: "59d2a245734d1d42e49ed55d",
pollName: "Favourite Colour",
createdBy: "John",
pollData: [
    {key: "blue", value: 5},
    {key: "green", value: 7},
    {key: "red", value: 4},
    {key: "orange",value: 1}
    ]
},
{
_id: "59d2a291734d1d42e49ed574",
pollName: "Favourite Ice Cream",
createdBy: "Peter",
pollData: [
    {key: "Chocolate", value: 12},
    {key: "Vanilla", value: 7},
    {key: "Strawberry", value: 10}
    ]
}
```

I am trying to map these into Pie Charts but get syntax errors.  This is the code in React:

```
render() {
    const {polls} = this.state

    return(

        <h1>Home</h1>

        {polls.map((poll, index) => (
            <div key={poll._id}>
                <Chart poll={poll} />
            </div>
        ))}

    )
}
```

The error message I get is on the opening brace:

> Unexpected token, expected ,
>
> > {polls.map((poll, index) => (

I have done this previously on another project and it worked fine mapping through an array of objects, then passing each object into a component.  Why is it not working in this instance?

Comment: wrap all the ui elements into a wrapper `div`, like this: `return(<div><h1>.......</div>)`, we can't return more than one elements.

Comment: That did it - thank you @MayankShukla

Comment: @PramendraGupta it is an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

There should be curly brackets istead of "( )"

```
    {polls.map((poll, index) => { 
     return <div key={poll._id}>
                <Chart poll={poll} />
            </div>  }
```

Comment: curly braces with return or () are equivalent syntaxes. Problem is what mayank mentioned in his comment

Comment: I have tried it both ways with the same syntax error

Answer (score 0):

```js
const polls = [
  {
    _id: "59d2a245734d1d42e49ed55d",
    pollName: "Favourite Colour",
    createdBy: "John",
    pollData: [
      {key: "blue", value: 5},
      {key: "green", value: 7},
      {key: "red", value: 4},
      {key: "orange",value: 1}
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "59d2a291734d1d42e49ed574",
    pollName: "Favourite Ice Cream",
    createdBy: "Peter",
    pollData: [
      {key: "Chocolate", value: 12},
      {key: "Vanilla", value: 7},
      {key: "Strawberry", value: 10}
    ]
  }
];


polls.map((poll, index) => {
  console.log(poll._id, poll.pollData)
});
```